# Como clicar em um botão usando Selenium em Python - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook

Sou novo em Python e Selenium e estou querendo clicar no botão abaixo. Já tentei diversas formas (não sei se da maneira correta) como XPATH, CLASS NAME, BUTTON TEXT etc e nenhuma funciona. Alguém consegue me ajudar em como selecionar e clicar esse botão?

```
<button ng-if="!usuarioLogadoSemContrato &amp;&amp; !dtoAutenticacao.usuario.contrato.isentoDePonto" type="button" class="btn blue-madison btn-lg btn-block ng-scope" ng-class="{'hidden': usuarioLogadoSemContrato}" ng-click="confirmarMarcacao()" style="">
                    <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>
                    <span class="ng-binding">Marcar Ponto</span>
                </button>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: verifique se essa parte da página não está dentro de um <iframe> .. Além disso, demonstre na pergunta quais formas você tentou para tentar ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Nao ficou claro na pergunda quais foram os testes utilizados.

Mas se você conseguiu chegar até no botão usando o selenium, pode usar uma das duas alternarivas (depende da situação).

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div//button/span").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='comp-save-btn']//button").submit()
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Já tentei "clicar" nesse botão de diversas formas usando o BY XPATH, BUTTON TEXT, NAME etc. Nenhuma das alternativas que sugeriu funcionaram, segue erro do método de submit:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath)
    519             stacklevel=2,
    520         )
--> 521         return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
    522 
    523     def find_elements_by_xpath(self, xpath) -> List[WebElement]:
```